# How to click in two different programs at the same time?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to be able to start a timer at the same time that i start a video in media player classic & also be able to pause both at the same time.

lets say that i have to click in the timer the one tha tis in the top left of the image and then click f1 or else the script does not work... also if i want to click it again after the first time it does not work properly..

[image: IMAGE with the idea of what i want to do]

I tried the following code:

```
F1::
MouseClick, left, 146, 115
MouseClick, left, 87, 300
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that adding

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
```

at the top of your script will help you achieve what you're looking to do.

However, I suggest you use ControlClick instead.

```
F1::
    ControlClick, x87 y300, Hourglass,, Left
    ControlClick, x100 y100, Media Player Classic,, Left
return
```

This will send a click to the x and y *relative to each window* regardless if they're on top or not (they cannot, however, be minimized)

(please note that you probably have to adjust the x and y coordinates)

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm

Comment: adding CoordMode ..... worked!
But the controlClick version did not work... i tried adjusting the coordinates using windowspy which gives you the position on screen, window, client (i always use the "screen" coords)
By the way when you click start on hourglass the title of the program changes to the time left for the timer to reach the  specified time (the example of the image is 24 min 6 sec) ... so i that probably why giving controlClick "hourglass" as window title did not work.

Comment: Since you're using windowspy, you can try one of the other alternatives it suggests.

Below is a screenshot of window spy when looking at the current chrome window. 
[screenshot](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1MiGAAHKyhYbMHdq37LujH-SwGfmCDPWb)


If hourglass is a homemade program of yours, and it will always only have one process running, you can use ahk_exe <filename> in place of Hourglass

So in my window spy screenshot, I would do 

`ControlClick, x87 y300, ahk_exe chrome.exe,, Left`

But with a bit of luck you might have some controllers in that gui that you could use instead.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of window spy when you hover the start button on your Hourglass app?

Comment: Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/qMzAsiA
The screenshot did not capture the cursor but it's on the start button.
Hourlglass is not a homemade program, is this one: https://chris.dziemborowicz.com/apps/hourglass/
Is a timer that can be used as a chronometer or simple to count up to X time you just have to change the settings to do so.

Answer (score 1):

From my (limited) experience, I believe even hotkeys will carry out actions sequentially i.e. one after the other, in most cases the time delay between clicks will be insignificant howeverwon't be exact.
If the timer (Hourglass) is something you have created yourself, I would maybe suggest adding another button or a hotkey specifically for this use case that adds; for example, a 0.5s delay before the timer begins & then starts the media 0.5s later allowing for them to work in tandem, but as far as starting both applications simultaneously I'm not aware of a method for this.

To clarify though, what was the actual issue with the quoted code above?

Comment: the problem with my code was that i had to first make sure that i'm on "hourlglass" (clicking anywhere on it) the press f1 or else just media player would start.
Then the other problem is that if i want to pause both i had to again make sure to click anywhere in the timer (hourglass)